# Accessibility issues when using Material-UI 'Menu' on top of a 'Drawer'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accessibility

I was having an accessibility issue when using Material-UI with React. Specifically when placing a Menu on a Drawer. Essentially the normal behaviour of a [Menu](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/) is to highlight the top [MenuItem](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/). This behaviour is different if that menu is placed on a Material UI [Drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/).

I have recreated the problem here using just the example Material-UI [Menu](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/) and [Drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/):

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-and-drawer-accessibility-issues-xjj3h?file=/src/App.js

The following images show the difference between the two menus when opened. I am using the chromevox extension while testing:

A normal menu when using chromevox to show accessability:

[image: A normal menu when using chromevox to show accessability]

A menu when it is placed on a material UI drawer:

[image: A menu when it is placed on a material UI drawer]

Would anyone be able to point out if this is an error in my code or if perhaps there are any workarounds? Was going to raise this as a new github issue but felt it was worth asking the question here first. :)

Comment: Your sandbox had one issue that adds some confusion when troubleshooting. Both menus were driving off of the same `anchorEl` state, I've updated it to use separate state for the two menus. I'll answer the key issue in a little bit.

Comment: Thank you so much Ryan, very appreciated! As are your edits to enable the images :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the drawer enforces (so long as it is open) that focus stays within itself. So when the menu opens and grabs focus, the drawer notices that it lost focus and it grabs it back.

There are two options for fixing this:

1. You can turn off this drawer behavior by specifying the `disableEnforceFocus` prop ([example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-and-drawer-accessibility-issues-fon2j?file=/src/App.js:2832-2864)).
2. You can specify the `disablePortal` prop on the menu ([example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-and-drawer-accessibility-issues-w7eje?file=/src/App.js:1706-1732)). This will cause the menu to be a descendant of the drawer in the DOM (by default the menu uses [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) and is added as a child of the `<body>` element), so the drawer will not try to "take back" the focus, because when focus is in the menu it will still be within the drawer.

I would recommend option 2 since the drawer's focus enforcement is generally a good thing from an accessibility standpoint.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you so much! This is incredibly useful! I look forward to giving it a go tomorrow morning. The second option certainly seems more useful as it applies to just the Menu in question and not the entire Drawer. 



Looking at the documentation on the Menu API (https://material-ui.com/api/menu/) I do not see a disablePortal prop. Can I ask how you knew about this? Is there a way for me to read up on 'generic' props that are not specifically listed? Or is it simply that you looked at the components being rendered and checked the documentation for them?

Comment: @LearningReact At the bottom of the Menu API documentation you'll see an [inheritance](https://material-ui.com/api/menu/#inheritance) section. This will take you to [Popover](https://material-ui.com/api/popover/). Popover's [inheritance](https://material-ui.com/api/popover/#inheritance) section will take you to [Modal](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props) where you'll find the `disablePortal` prop.

Comment: @LearningReact This shortcoming in the documentation is documented here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18288. It is likely to be addressed for v5.

Comment: Hi Ryan, unfortunately the disablePortal solution has not worked well for me and screen readers do not read out the menu items. I have tried adding an aria-label to the menu items to no avail. I wonder if you know how I can proceed to have the menuItems read out. Appreciate all the help :)

Comment: @LearningReact What screen reader are you using? I just tried it out using Windows Narrator and Narrator does seem to interfere with the focus management (I can't use the keyboard to select menu items after it opens), but I see this problem in both menus (both inside and outside of the drawer). Both work as I would expect (as far as keyboard support) if I have Narrator turned off. This seems like an issue with Narrator, so I'm curious whether other screen readers have the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, first of all apologies for the lack of formatting! And thanks for having a look!

I have tested the disablePortal workaround with:   
  
- Works well using the IOS inbuilt screen reader. 
- Does not work on ChromeVox (which I believe to be depreciated).    
- Has issues using Jaws (on Windows) where the menu items didn't inform me how many other menu items there are. (Which is inconsistent behaviour compared to other menus)

Comment: @LearningReact With Jaws, are you still able to use the keyboard to navigate to the other menu items (even though it doesn't tell you that they are there)? Does the `disableEnforceFocus` approach work any better with Jaws? I don't have Jaws on my machine, so I can't really troubleshoot solutions specific to that. I was primarily testing the solution by solely using the keyboard (which works fine).

Comment: Hi Ryan... yep Jaws actually does work a lot better. The only thing it misses is the 'button 1 of 3' text. (for all other menu's it gives a count of how many menu items exist, which is behaviour other screen readers reproduce) May not be entirely vital but it just seems strange it isn't treating the menu in the same way it treats other menu's.

Comment: @LearningReact Perhaps the difference is the structure of the content in the drawer. You have the menu inside of a list item. Does it behave differently if you remove the `List` and `ListItem` wrapper around the button and menu in the drawer?

Comment: Hi @ryan, can confirm the behaviour is the same even outside of the wrapper. As can be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-and-drawer-accessibility-workaround-k724d

Comment: @LearningReact Sorry, but I don't really have any more insight to provide. When the `disablePortal` prop is in place, the remaining problems seem to be more about quirks of the screen readers than anything "wrong" (as far as roles/focus) with what Material-UI is doing. The screen readers appear to interfere with the focus management to varying degrees, and as far as not reading the other menu items -- it seems that the screen reader is being impacted by something that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I appreciate all your help with this and agree its likely a screen reader issue. Different screenreaders provide different results. I think the most consistent improvement was when I added the disablePortal prop. I actually made a issue on the M-UI githhub too to make them aware of the slight issues but suspect with your help I have it at a point where its 'good enough' for the major screenreaders :)